# Thread synchronization from Swing Component

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronization

I failed after a lot for tries to synchronize my main task with its substask (thread). I haven't found any example when calling from a swing component.

I created a white panel on which I display a clip movie.  This works pretty well.
However, as soon, as the Thread terminates, I want to take control back in the main task.  It seems after  "setVisible(true) the next instructions are not executed. I also tried with a loop  issuing  sleep for 1 second, but it was not executed.   Here is my last code.

```
     /* Auteur: Gérard MARTINELLI  */
     import gegeutil.Gegetools;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.util.Vector;
     import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
     import java.awt.Color;
     
     public class JouerClip extends javax.swing.JDialog   
     
      
     /*    Variables et constantes  */
        
     public static final long serialVersionUID = 1401213293925293574L;
     
     public     static String  titre       =   "",
                            film         =   "";
     protected  Thread      th           =   new Thread();
     protected  boolean     inService    =   false,
                           internal     =   false;
     public static Process process     =    null;
     public static  String videoplayer  =   "E:/PotPlayer/PotPlayerMini64.exe";
     public static  String pathFilm     =   "F:/Films";
     
        public JouerClip(JFrame owner, String  filmName, boolean inter) // constructeur
     { 
        super(owner,true);
        if (Gegetools.isEmpty(filmName)) setVisible(false); 
        film =   filmName;
        internal = inter;
         initialize();
     }
      
     public void initialize() 
     {    
        setSize(1136, 873);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        th = new Thread() 
        {
              public void run() 
              {
                   System.out.println("Thread  running");
                    
               jouer(pathFilm+"/" + film); 
                   System.out.println("Thread stopped");
                   inService= false;
              }
          };
          inService= true;
          th.start();
          setVisible(true);
          System.out.println("I continue the main task");
          try 
          {
               CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
               latch.await(); // Wait for countdown
               this.setVisible(false);
               if (internal) System.exit(0); else this.setVisible(false);
              } 
         catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
     }
     
     public static void jouer( String path) 
     {
        //  This works pretty well. 
        // When the clip ends, the videoplayer has  gone. 
     }
     
     public static void main(String[] agrs) 
     {
             new JouerClip(new JFrame(), "Seven.mp4", true);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have resolved my concern.  In the JDialog ContenPane, I have created a JButton  with an actionListener, then before leaving the run method, I issue a doClic().  This execute what I want (for example return to the caller).  It works perfectly.